# how to access div tags of user control in master page

Tags: asp.net

Can we access div tags of user control in Master page? I am trying to change the background color for each one of the div tags on some event.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work (in C#):

```
Control myControl = this.Page.Master.FindControl("[Your name here]");
```

Then you can do whatever you would like to the control. If it's a Panel control (for the div) you can cast it that way, or if you are using an HTML server side control, you can cast it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to make a public property in the user control that you can then set directly from the masterpage.

Comment: I am trying to set the property from master page but nothing is happening to back ground color of div tag